# Search Wikidata SPARQL for movies or tv series by title

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I want to search "Star Wars" across both TV series (`http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q5398426`) and films (`http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q11424`).  The following SPARQL is for searching movies:

```
# search movies by name
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?name WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q11424.
  ?item rdfs:label ?queryByTitle.
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P1476 ?name. }
  #FILTER(REGEX(?queryByTitle, "star wars", "i"))
  FILTER(contains(lcase(?queryByTitle), "star wars"))
}
LIMIT 100
```

Any idea how I can search by TV Series as well?

Comment: Replace `?item wdt:P31 wd:Q11424.` with `VALUES ?type {wd:Q5398426 wd:Q11424}
  ?item wdt:P31 ?type .`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@AKSW answered the question.  Here's the full gist for anyone searching in the future.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?name WHERE {
  VALUES ?type {wd:Q5398426 wd:Q11424} ?item wdt:P31 ?type .
  ?item rdfs:label ?queryByTitle.
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P1476 ?name. }
  FILTER(REGEX(?queryByTitle, "star wars", "i"))
}
LIMIT 100
```